# Iterable Object conversion to another Iterable Object while iterating with Serialization support

Tags: java, serialization, iterator, data-conversion, iterable

At the beginning: I did not found any information which might be helpful on internet resources.

I do have some issue while trying to convert iterated object to new one when serialization support is required. 
Basically lets assume that some complicated process in application **AP1** is giving you an **Iterable** interface to some large **Collection** of objects i.e. **BaseClass** type. Part of the data received from these objects should be used in another application **AP2** as a new object i.e. **TargetClass** type. Conversion between these two objects **BaseClass->TargetClass** is quite complicated and needs to be performed before object would be sent to target application. 
**Any ideas how to achieve that?**

Some simplified example placed below presents the issue. Code is runnable. One test "*testForTargetDataSource_with_Serialization()*" of 4 test cases fails with cause "*java.lang.ClassCastException: IterableTest$TargetDataSource$1 cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable*".

The cause of this exception is quite obvious while in **next()** method I'm using plenty of different objects to make a conversion and these objects are not Serializable (you can refer to *public TargetClass next()* - In real example this is very complex.).

```
public TargetClass next() {
    BaseClass bcObj = dsIterator.next();
    return new TargetClass(bcObj.getFirstName(), bcObj.getSecondName());
}
```

Same issue would be with **hasNext()** method of *TargetDataSource*.

EXAMPLE:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotSame;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

public class IterableTest implements Serializable {

@Test
public void testForStandardDataSource() {
    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    Iterator<BaseClass> iterator = ds.getData().iterator();
    assertEquals("B", iterator.next().getSecondName());
    assertEquals("C", iterator.next().getSecondName());
    assertEquals("D", iterator.next().getSecondName());
}

@Test
public void testForTargetDataSource() {
    TargetDataSource tdc = new TargetDataSource();
    Iterator<TargetClass> iter = tdc.getData().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iter.next().getFullName());
    }
}

@Test
public void testForStandardDataSource_with_Serialization() {
    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    Iterable<BaseClass> iter = ds.getData();

    byte[] bytes = SerializationUtils.serialize((Serializable) iter);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Iterable<BaseClass> iter2 = (Iterable<BaseClass>) SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
    assertNotSame(iter, iter2);

    Iterator<BaseClass> iterator = iter2.iterator();
    assertEquals("B", iterator.next().getSecondName());
    assertEquals("C", iterator.next().getSecondName());
    assertEquals("D", iterator.next().getSecondName());
}

@Test
public void testForTargetDataSource_with_Serialization() {
    TargetDataSource tdc = new TargetDataSource();
    Iterable<TargetClass> iter = tdc.getData();

    byte[] bytes = SerializationUtils.serialize((Serializable) iter);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Iterable<TargetClass> iter2 = (Iterable<TargetClass>) SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
    assertNotSame(iter, iter2);

    Iterator<TargetClass> iterator = iter2.iterator();
    assertEquals("A B", iterator.next().getFullName());
    assertEquals("A C", iterator.next().getFullName());
    assertEquals("A D", iterator.next().getFullName());
}

class BaseClass implements Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;

    public BaseClass(String firstName, String secondName) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }
}

class TargetClass implements Serializable {

    private String fullName;

    public TargetClass() {
    }

    public TargetClass(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

}

class DataSource {
    private final List<BaseClass> data = Arrays.asList(new BaseClass("A", "B"), new BaseClass("A", "C"),
            new BaseClass("A", "D"));

    public Iterable<BaseClass> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

class TargetDataSource {
    final DataSource ds = new DataSource();

    Iterator<BaseClass> dsIterator = ds.getData().iterator();

    public Iterable<TargetClass> getData() {
        return new Iterable<TargetClass>() {

            public Iterator<TargetClass> iterator() {
                return new Iterator<TargetClass>() {

                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return dsIterator.hasNext();
                    }

                    public TargetClass next() {
                        BaseClass bcObj = dsIterator.next();
                        return new TargetClass(bcObj.getFirstName(), bcObj.getSecondName());
                    }

                    public void remove() {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                };
            }


        };
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you are trying to serialize `new Iterable<TargetClass>() { ... }`, which is not serializable. In your `DataSource` class, `getData` returns a `List`, which is serializable. If you want to serialize the result of your `getData`, you need to make it return a serializable object.

Comment: @njzk2 Yes I know that but how to achieve it? I can make it returning serializable object but it would not solve my problem. I was even trying that and other approaches but the real issue is inside this implemented next(){..} method which converts one object to another. In that method there are multiple objects involved and I cannot and should not serialize them. How to change behavior to really return only serialized object with it's iterator?

Comment: why don't you create a list from the transformed objects?

Comment: you can return `<T extends Iterable & Serializable>` if you really want to limit to iterables and not accept lists, but you still need an actual type that does both.

Comment: @njzk2 of course converting from one list to another, serialize\deserialize it would be the simplest solution but I cannot do that while mentioned list can contain for example 65k records. From that reason elements are taken one by one but these conversion from one type to another while iterating causes issues and currently I do not have idea how to fix that.

Comment: you are serializing. so at some point you need to have all elements in hand to pass them to the serialization process.

Comment: if you are looking into sending a stream of object as bytes, you can serialize them one by one, and read them one by one from the bytes